# effective way to bypass Sucuri WAF on Sqlmap?

Tags: sqlmap, waf

i'm struggling to bypass a website WAF that uses Sucuri WAF, i saw some tutorials online, and tried to mix them with some pre-defined sqlmap tampers, such as "randomcaso, charencode", but i wasn't able to succeed, it's like the browser and the sqlmap requests differ, but it both has the same headers, any thoughts?